# How to post current time when checkbox = TRUE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'll try to keep this short and sweet.

I am making a [packaging form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnCyL.png) using Google Sheets. Users fill out the form using the dropdowns on the spreadsheet and press the `Submit` button to send the data to `Packaging Form Responses`. This script works perfectly. Now I'm struggling to write a script to make it so that the checkbox in cell O13 auto-populates the data in the "Time Out" section in row 13 with the current time. You'll notice that I have the current time broken down into different cells on row 24 (hh , mm , am/pm). Basically, when the checkbox is = TRUE, I want the data in row 24 to be posted in row 13's "Time Out" section (side note: rows 22-24 will be hidden when the form is live). Haven't used onEdit() function very much so I could use some help here.

Here is my code thus far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var column = range.getColumn;
  var row = range.getRow;
  var hours = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Packaging Form').getRange('H24').getValue();
  var minutes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Packaging Form').getRange('I24').getValue();
  var ampm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Packaging Form').getRange('J24').getValue();
  
  if(column == 15 && row == 13){  
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Packaging Form').getRange('D13').setValue(hours);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Packaging Form').getRange('F13').setValue(minutes);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Packaging Form').getRange('H13').setValue(ampm)    
  } 
}
```

Not sure what is wrong here, I believe it has to do with my local variables `hours`, `minutes`, and `ampm`.

Also I haven't gotten this far yet, but would like for the current time that gets posted in row 13 to be cleared when the checkbox no longer = TRUE (i.e. when the user un-checks the "Use current time" checkbox, the data in the "Time Out" section is cleared). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
  var column = range.getColumn;
  var row = range.getRow;
```

by

```
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
```

or even better

```
  var column = range.columnStart;
  var row = range.rowStart;
```

P.S. you might also change `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` by `spreadsheet`.

Comment: Thank you very much Rubén! Adding parentheses to getRow and getColumn worked perfectly